# finding Remainder without actually dividing

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the remainder when $6^{17}$ + $17^{6}$ is divided by 7 without actually performing the division

Comment: Have you learnt modular arithmetic?

Comment: No, I haven't learnt modular arithmetic.

Comment: For the remainder of $17^6=17^{7-1}$ when divided through the prime number $7$, see [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have easily the result using the modular arithmetic

$$6^{17}+17^6\equiv -1+3^6\equiv-1+9^3\equiv-1+2^3=7\equiv0\mod7$$

Comment: Though I haven't studied modular arithmetic , I understood the procedure you have followed. Can I apply the same method to similar questions? Also , is there any other way?

Comment: Is this question a homework? If you haven't studied yet modular arithmetic I think that you don't allowed to used it, I'm not sure.

Comment: No, this isn't a homework question. I wanted the solution for quantitative aptitude.

Comment: So in this case you can use it but it's useful for you to learn it a bit see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

Fermat little theorem gives: $$6^6 = 1  \mod 7 \Rightarrow 6^{12} = 1  \mod 7 $$ and $$6^5 = 6 \mod 7\Rightarrow 6^{17} = 6  \mod 7 $$ and $$17^6 = 1 \mod 7 \Rightarrow 6^{17} + 17^6 = 1 + 6  = 0 \mod 7$$